# Angular Material Transparent Toolbar

Tags: html, css, material-design

I'm using angular material on a rails app, want a toolbar to sit on top of an image and make that toolbar clear so you can see the image behind it. Here is the code so far:

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill>
<div layout="row">
    <img src="http://www.outsideonline.com/sites/default/files/styles/full-page/public/yosemite-smart-black-bear_h.jpg?itok=kKS8ILd9">
    <md-toolbar id="toolbar" class="transparent">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span>Turbo Mortgages</span>
            <!-- fill up the space between left and right area -->
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button ui-sref="app.register"
                       aria-label="Toggle Mobile Navigation">
                About
            </md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref="app.join"
                       aria-label="Toggle Mobile Navigation">
                Join
            </md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref="app.login"
                       aria-label="Toggle Mobile Navigation">
                Login
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
</div>
<md-content>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</md-content>
```

and what I see on the page right now is just the image...here is the css:

```
#toolbar {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

how do i get the toolbar to lay on top of the image if not with z-index? thanks for help!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am having similar requirements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up making the image the background of the toolbar...You could also set the

```
position: absolute
background-color:transparent
```

on the toolbar to place it over the image